# Parse string data to jsonutl class and give me error in return void

Tags: android

```
    public class JsonUtils {  

 public JsonUtils() throws JSONException {
    }

    public static Sandwich parseSandwichJson(String json) throws JSONException {

    String jsonStr = new String();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String mainName = jsonobject.getString("mainName");
        String alsoKnownAs = jsonobject.getString("alsoKnownAs");
        String placeOfOrigin = jsonobject.getString("placeOfOrigin");
        String description = jsonobject.getString("description");
        String image = jsonobject.getString("image");
        String ingredients = jsonobject.getString("ingredients");

        return ;
    }


}
```

i want to solve the error in return; line and solve the problem

in this i try to get parse json and need to void return

Comment: there is a return in your loop which returns nothing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove return from your `for` loop and also your method return type is `Sandwich` change it to `void` like:

```
public static void parseSandwichJson(String json) throws JSONException
```